Update rows for generic vs specific inputs
I have a table with structure, all not nullable.
table1: col1, col2, col3, col4
Table1 Data:
col1  col2  col3  col4
======================
kc11  kc21  kc31  100
kc11  kc21  kc32  125
kc11  kc22  kc31  150
kc11  kc22  kc32  105
kc11  kc22  kc33  106
kc11  kc22  kc34  107
kc11  kc22  kc35  108

A client application sends data update in JSON format. Col1 to 3 are keys with value in col4.
Values in col3 can be null, which means it applies to all rows matching just col1&2. The data may contain specific entries for col3 that need be applied instead of the one with null.
I load the data into @input with the same column names.
@input loaded:
col1  col2  col3  col4
======================
kc11  kc21  null  160
kc11  kc22  null  175
kc11  kc22  kc32  125

I am trying to come up with a query that will update table1 from @input but don't know how to join the tables such that specific col3 entries are updated from rows with col3 values in @input.
update table1
set col4=inp.col4
from table1 tbl1
inner join @input inp on tbl1.col1=inp.col1 and tbl1.col2=inp.col2 and ?

Is there a single query I can write to get the below result?
Table1 Data updated:
col1  col2  col3  col4
======================
kc11  kc21  kc31  160
kc11  kc21  kc32  160
kc11  kc22  kc31  175
kc11  kc22  kc32  125
kc11  kc22  kc33  175
kc11  kc22  kc34  175
kc11  kc22  kc35  175

Test below did not provide the desired result:
declare @table1 table
(
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(10),
col3 varchar(10),
col4  varchar(10)
);

insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc21','kc31','100');
insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc21','kc32','125');
insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22','kc31','150');
insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22','kc32','105');
insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22','kc33','106');
insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22','kc34','107');
insert @table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22','kc35','108');

declare @input table
(
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(10),
col3 varchar(10),
col4  varchar(10)
);

insert @input (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc21',  null,'160');
insert @input (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22',  null,'175');
insert @input (col1,col2,col3,col4) values ('kc11','kc22','kc32','125');

select * from @table1;
update @table1
set col4=inp.col4
from @table1 tbl1
inner join @input inp on tbl1.col1=inp.col1 and tbl1.col2=inp.col2 
    and (inp.col3 is null or inp.col3 = tbl1.col3)

select * from @table1;

Query output:
col1       col2       col3       col4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
kc11       kc21       kc31       100
kc11       kc21       kc32       125
kc11       kc22       kc31       150
kc11       kc22       kc32       105
kc11       kc22       kc33       106
kc11       kc22       kc34       107
kc11       kc22       kc35       108

Desired output:
col1       col2       col3       col4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
kc11       kc21       kc31       160
kc11       kc21       kc32       160
kc11       kc22       kc31       175
kc11       kc22       kc32       175
kc11       kc22       kc33       175
kc11       kc22       kc34       175
kc11       kc22       kc35       175


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

fwiw, I'd do this differently if the existing data can have NULL values in column 3, so that would be useful information to have in the question.

Updated with more information.

There might be faster ways, but I'd go for a CROSS APPLY TOP 1 solution, something like:
SELECT  *, col4 AS col4_old
INTO #data
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'kc11', N'kc21', N'kc31', 100)
    ,   (N'kc11', N'kc21', N'kc32', 125)
    ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', N'kc31', 150)
    ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', N'kc32', 105)
    ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', N'kc33', 106)
    ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', N'kc34', 107)
    ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', N'kc35', 108)
) t (col1,col2,col3,col4)


UPDATE  t
SET col4 = y.col4
FROM    #data t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  TOP 1 *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'kc11', N'kc21', NULL, 160)
        ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', NULL, 175)
        ,   (N'kc11', N'kc22', N'kc32', 125)
        ) n (col1,col2,col3,col4)
    WHERE   n.col1 = t.col1
    AND n.col2 = t.col2
    AND (n.col3 IS NULL OR n.col3 = t.col3) -- Sanity check
    ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN n.col3 = t.col3 THEN 0 -- Exact match
            ELSE 1 -- col3 is NULL
        END
    ) y

Basically, I try to find the best match by taking TOP 1 ordered by exact match and then null.
To avoid updating too many rows, I've added AND (n.col3 IS NULL OR n.col3 = t.col3), this makes sure we won't update from any other random row.
Final result:



col1
col2
col3
col4
col4_old




kc11
kc21
kc31
160
100


kc11
kc21
kc32
160
125


kc11
kc22
kc31
175
150


kc11
kc22
kc32
125
105


kc11
kc22
kc33
175
106


kc11
kc22
kc34
175
107


kc11
kc22
kc35
175
108




It did work with the data I provided in the question. Thank you.

and (inp.col3 IS NULL OR inp.col3 = tb1.Col3)


If you can know the existing table1 data will not have NULL in col3, I would do it like this:
update table1
set col4=inp.col4
from table1 tbl1
inner join @input inp on tbl1.col1=inp.col1 and tbl1.col2=inp.col2 
    and tbl1.col3 = coalesce(inp.col3, tbl1.col3)

I like it over alternatives with OR because it gives you at least a chance to use an index with the column, but you have be certain existing data won't be NULL.
If the existing column can be NULL, I would do this, because it matches my first option more closely:
update table1
set col4=inp.col4
from table1 tbl1
inner join @input inp on tbl1.col1=inp.col1 and tbl1.col2=inp.col2 
    and coalesce(tbl1.col3,'') = coalesce(inp.col3, tbl1.col3,'')

However, the coalesce() on both sides means indexes with col3 will not be any help.
Or I would do this, which is what you'll see suggested more often elsewhere online:
update table1
set col4=inp.col4
from table1 tbl1
inner join @input inp on tbl1.col1=inp.col1 and tbl1.col2=inp.col2 
    and (inp.col3 is null or inp.col3 = tbl1.col3)


Please see the updates to the question. I am not getting the desired result.
